# How to transfer a 60mb file to queue using MQ FTE

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I am trying to transfer a 60mb file to queue, but [Websphere MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq) fte stall the transfer and keep recovering. I am running WebSphere MQ FTE on default configuration.

Comment: You have not provided much information on the problem. At what point does the transfer stalls and recover? Is the destination agent up and running?

Comment: Both source & destination agents are running (other transfer are running successfully), the time fte trigger the transfer it right away changes its status to stalled. In fte trace I can see some messages moving but in destination queue I don't see any messages. Its always empty.

Comment: I think it's best to speak to IBM regarding this as other transfers are running.

Comment: We already created a PMR with IBM, trying other options.

Comment: In what way are you transferring this file to a queue? Do you have code for this? I suspect the question could do with a lot more detail (if the `enableQueueInputOutput=true` is relevant please edit it in).

Answer (score 2):

I have tested following scenario with different results according to configuration changes I made.

These commands were issued to create monitor:

```
fteCreateTransfer -sa AGENT1 -sm TQM.FTE -da AGENT2 -dm QM.FTE -dq FTE.TEST.Q -p QM.FTE -de overwrite -sd delete -gt /var/IBM/WMQFTE/config/TQM.FTE/TEST_TRANSFER.xml D:\\rvs\\tstusrdat\\ALZtoSIP\\INC\\*.zip

fteCreateMonitor -ma AGENT1 -mn TEST_MONITOR -md D:\\rvs\\tstusrdat\\ALZtoSIP\\INC -mt /var/IBM/WMQFTE/config/TQM.FTE/TEST_TRANSFER.xml -tr match,*.zip
```

Test was performed on files: 53MB and 30MB

Default configuration (just enableQueueInputOutput=true added to AGENT2.properties)

1) all default

1. no success, transfer status: "recovering"
2. for both files

2) added maxInputOutputMessageLength=60000000, destination queue max message length changed to 103809024

1. result transfer status: "failed" with following exception PM71138: BFGIO0178E: A QUEUE WRITE FAILED DUE TO A WMQAPIEXCEPTION WITH MESSAGE TEXT CC=2 RC=2142 MQRC_HEADER_ERROR
2. for both files

After reading this: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/message_length.htm I came with working settings:

3) `maxInputOutputMessageLength=34603008` (its maximum value), destination queue max message length still to 103809024

1. result for file with size 30MB: succcess
2. result for file with size 53MB: "failed" with following exception PM71138: BFGIO0178E: A QUEUE WRITE FAILED DUE TO A WMQAPIEXCEPTION WITH MESSAGE TEXT CC=2 RC=2142 MQRC_HEADER_ERROR

So according to this I am afraid one can't transfer larger then 34603008 bytes.

Comment: Sorry I never replied to this post... I didn't get any real answer from IBM. I guess I kind of figure out how to deal with this kind of situations. Are you transferring whole file (53MB and 30MB file) as a single message?

Answer (score 0):

If you are transferring file to queue you definitely can't use the default settings. You have to add "enableQueueInputOutput=true" to agent.properties for agent thet uses queue as source or destination.

Comment: sorry for confusion .. I though "enableQueueInputOutput=true" is basic setting for file to queue transfer. When I say default I mean setting which effect file to queue transfer.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I could have figure it out myself :) . anyway I posted hopefuly more appropriate answer after some testing. BTW: did IBM solved your PMR??